# How do i use IN clause in JPA ExampleMatcher?

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to create a `search` API in Spring boot using rest. I am getting the hang of `ExampleMatchers` in JPA to filter & search. There is a particular scenario where I need to filter through multiple values as in a list of values for a particular field

Below are the JPA entities:

```
public class ETopic {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "id")
  int id;

  @Column(name = "topic_name")
  String topicName;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "tenant_id", nullable = false)
  @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SELECT)
  @JsonBackReference
  ETenant tenant;
}


public class ETenant {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    int id;

    @Column(name = "tenant_name")
    String tenantName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "tenant")
    @JsonManagedReference
    List<ERole> roles;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "tenant")
    @JsonManagedReference
    List<ETopic> topics;
}
```

I need to fetch `ETopic` using multiple `ETenant` names

I have not been able to find anything in example matchers to use IN clause

```
var pageable = Pageable.ofSize(request.getPageSize()).withPage(request.getPageNo());

ExampleMatcher exampleMatcher =
        ExampleMatcher.matchingAny()
            .withMatcher(
                "topicName", ExampleMatcher.GenericPropertyMatchers.contains().ignoreCase())
            .withMatcher("tenant", ExampleMatcher.GenericPropertyMatchers.contains());

List<ETenant> tenants = List.of(ETenant.builder().id(3).build(), ETenant.builder().id(4).build());  // unable to use this

ETopic eTopicEg = ETopic.builder().topicName(request.getSearchTerm()).tenant(ETenant.builder().id(3).build()).build();
Example<ETopic> example = Example.of(eTopicEg, exampleMatcher);
Page<ETopic> eTopics = topicRepository.findAll(example, pageable);
```